# EventListener for focus change?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to add an event listener to an input where by the focus changes from `onfocus` to something like `off focus`

Basically i have an event listener assigned to my input box using `key up`, this then calls my server to check if the username is taken already in the database.

The problem is - this will call every time the user presses a letter, i would rather wait until they are no longer focussed in the input box to check the database, so i can reduce the amount of calls?

What would the best option be for event listening to do this ? As it seems silly to check when user is still typing in the box.

I currently have:

```
mydiv.addEventListener("keyup",name_exist_validation(),false);
```

Comment: Note: Those `()` after `name_exist_validation` are calling the function rather than letting it be passed as a reference for binding.

Comment: Ah that saved me asking my next question, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Event name `Blur` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/blur

```
<element onblur="SomeJavaScriptCode">
```

Comment: And the obligatory [w3fools link](http://www.w3fools.com/). Try [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.onblur).

Answer (score 0):

```
mydiv.addEventListener("blur",name_exist_validation,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other sites eg Wordpress use a timer aswell as the Blur event as sdespont said.